# Open specific file in Microsoft Teams straight from File Explorer? (Not in SharePoint, nor Office)

Tags: windows-explorer, onedrive, microsoft-teams, teams

The title explains what I'm trying to do. I've tried this by selecting a file on my synced OneDrive/SharePoint, selecting "Open With", and choosing Teams.exe from the following path: "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe"

Of course it doesn't work. File Explorer will open the "home page" of Teams instead of opening the specific file *within* Teams.
So am I missing something, or does a custom file handler need to be created for this to be an option? Is anyone aware of a third party file handler developed just for this purpose?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not currently possible to open a specific file in Microsoft Teams straight from File Explorer. As you mentioned, selecting "Open With" and choosing Teams.exe will only open the home page of Teams. It is possible that a custom file handler could be created for this purpose, but I am not aware of any third-party file handlers developed specifically for this.

Comment: Thanks... yeah figured as much. I'm not a developer and this isn't the site for it, but I guess it's too niche for anyone to bother with creating.